# Is most of what everything is made from in another dimension?

Tags: string-theory, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

If there are eleven dimensions as M-Theory asserts would that mean that the majority of what we are made from exists in the seven other dimensions?

Comment: Nobody has found even a shred of evidence that nature is more than three dimensional... that should probably tell you something about "M-Theory".

Answer (score 2):

> If there are eleven dimensions as M-Theory asserts

Let us suppose it is true

> would that mean that the majority of what we are made from exists in the seven other dimensions?

Define [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension):

> In physics and mathematics, the dimension of a mathematical space (or object) is informally defined as the minimum number of coordinates needed to specify any point within it

Take an ant walking on the table.

**All** of what the ant is  made from exists in three dimensions, although one of the three dimensions has boundary conditions on the length of the coordinates needed to describe its (x,y,z); the third dimension describing the body of the ant is bound within a few millimeters, the size it can stretch in a third dimension.

In an analogous fashion, if eleven dimensions are true, ALL of what we are made of exists in all the dimensions, i.e. has a coordinate point in all dimensions, except, (since we do not interact with 7 of them) in seven of them the length of the coordinate line needed to describe our (x,y,z,t,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)  coordinate location is ,according to the theory, very very small.  In addition, the theory [curls the extra dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory)

> In the limit where these curled up dimensions become very small, one obtains a theory in which spacetime has effectively a lower number of dimensions

the ones we observe currently.

So we exist, have a coordinate, equally in all dimensions, but are aware and interact within the space time we have recorded with our experiments up to now. We are in a worse position than the ant in three dimensions, as our extra dimensions are so tiny we cannot record interactions with them, as the  ant can, by climbing over branches of a tree.

That is, if M theory becomes the theory of everything.